# The show apps button on the dock doesn't work 23.10

Tags: bug-reporting, 23.10

The question says most of it, I was using `23.04` and updated to `23.10` and now the show apps button doesn't work.
When I click on it, It changes color and that's it.
Why is this happening?
If you need any specs please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

This could be "upgrade pain". Sometimes, an upgrade introduces some errors due to mismatches of the current configuration with the new version.

You can check whether your user configuration is the cause by temporarily making a new account, and logging in there.